# Maven WebService with https connection

Tags: java, ssl, https, maven

i want to make a WebService which get a SOAP Message about https.
I make a standalone java client and server which can talk over https, but i can´t make a ServerSocket in my WebService.
I you use the Maven Eclipseplugin to build my WebService, but i didn´t find options for https in maven.
Can anybody help my, to reserve a SOAP Message in my WebService with https?

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know there is no relation between the web service and its protocol, http/https.
check that your server certificate is valid and has the correct server name. other wise you'll get an ssl exception.
if this doesnt help, you better post you stack trace here...

Comment: Stack trace and your POM.  If you're using jetty, I'm not sure you can do SSL from inside maven.

Comment: If i understood you right, you mean the WebService has no influence of the protocol. I create a ServerSocket in my WebService Operation and if i send a SOAP Message with soapUI to my WebService, i get a BindException with "Address already in use". I think it is my WebService, and i can`t create a new ServerSocket on the same port. And no i don`t use jetty. For what is this plugin?